# CSV exported from SQL Server in utf-8

Tags: sql-server, encoding, utf-8

I've exported data from SQL Server using the export data wizard. I did not select the UTF-8 checkbox.

When I view this file in VS Code, notepad++ etc it says it's `utf8`.

I am obviously misunderstanding the function of the UTF-8 checkbox in the export data wizard.

Would appreciate any expertise to enlighten me on why the file is still UTF-8.

Comment: I doubt it is in UTF-8, and more likely Notepad++ has defaulted to UTF-8. This is often the default encode such IDE's assume, when it's not apparent from the file.

Comment: If _all_ characters in the exported data are ASCII (codepoints under `U+0080`) then a file is considered `UTF-8` (as ASCII is a proper subset of UTF-8)…

Comment: If Notepad++ doesn't actually say `UTF-8-BOM` in the status bar then it's only guessing that the file is UTF-8 format. When it says `BOM` the file has a "preamble" or Byte Order Mark, U+FEFF, encoded as the UTF-8 byte sequence 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF. In VS Code you can open the file using the Hex Editor extension to confirm the absence or presence of the byte sequence.